# Difference between django.contrib.auth.login and django.contrib.auth.views.login

Tags: django, authentication

What's the difference to use `django.contrib.auth.login` or `django.contrib.auth.views.login`? First in `__init__.py` and second in `views.py` I saw that code and it differs from each other. Same is with some other views, for example 'logout'. As I understand, `django.contrib.auth.views.login` is used when I want to redefine some parametrs of that view?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`django.contrib.auth.login` is the actual action of signing in the user.

`django.contrib.auth.views.login` is a view that renders an HTML login form on GET request and handles POST request which internally calls `django.contrib.auth.login`.